# PHP insert string to existing url

Tags: php

I am new to php and i am currently working a sort/filter search page. but i can't figure out how to achieve what i want.

Example:
existing url: www.exaple.com/rentals?state=ca&city=el+monte

State:  California   New York   Maryland Virginia ...

City:   El Monte ...

Room: 1 Bedroom  2 Bedroom 3 Bedroom ...

Price:  High to Low  Low to High

How to pass existing url to the link?
For example when i click on High to Low and its url should be:
www.exaple.com/rentals?state=ca&city=el+monte&sort=pricel

Here is the part of php code i am working on:

```
echo($_GET['state'] == "CA"))? "<i class=\"current\">CA</i>":"<i><a href=\"http://www.exaple.com/rentals?state=ca\">CA</a></i>";

echo($_GET['sort'] == "pricel"))? "<i class=\"current\">High to low</i>":"<i><a href=\"http://www.exaple.com/rentals?sort=pricel\">High to low</a></i>";

echo($_GET['bedroom'] == "1"))? "<i class=\"current\">1 Bedroom</i>":"<i><a href=\"http://www.exaple.com/rentals?bedroom=1\">1 Bedroom</a></i>";
```

And when i click on Maryland and it will refresh the page and show its cities.

The hyperlink of Maryland should be:
www.exaple.com/rentals?state=md

Hyperlink of Baltimore(One of Maryland Cities) should be 
www.exaple.com/rentals?state=md&city=baltimore

But if i click on the Price: High to low, Its hyperlink is:
www.exaple.com/rentals?sort=pricel

and hyperlink of bedroom is:
www.exaple.com/rentals?bedroom=1

My question is how to pass strings to other links so they will become:
for Maryland state and 1 bedroom hyperlink - www.exaple.com/rentals?state=md&bedroom=1

Comment: Sorry! I don't know to explain it in English as it is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is a bit vague but from what i understood you want to post your value from the form being used to another page to achieve this,

in the form code of php specify the the `action='page to want data to go'` and in `method='GET'`

so according to the url given by you it should be:

```
<form action='rentals.php' method='GET'>
```